# How to replace react component with another when event triggered in that component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So, i (Total react beginner) have this React component.

```
import './cryptography.css';
import {useRef} from 'react';
import useInterval from 'react-useinterval';
import { useState } from 'react';

const DisplayTimer = () => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    useInterval(() => {
        setTime(time + 1);
    }
        , 1000);

    const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
    const seconds = time % 60;

    return (
        <div className="timer">
            <h3>Timer</h3>
            <p>{hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:{minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:{seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const CryptoOne = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    function verifyAnswer() {
        if (inputRef.current.value === "c6e24b99a8054ab24dd0323530b80819") {
            alert("Correct!");
        }
        else {
            alert("Wrong!");
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="crypto-one">
            <h3>Level One</h3>
            <p>Convert this plaintext into an MD5 hash - "RollingStonesGatherNoMoss"</p>

            <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="one-answer" name="one-answer" />
            <button onClick={verifyAnswer}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const CryptoTwo = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    function verifyAnswer() {
        if (inputRef.current.value === "IaMaHackerManHaHa") {
            alert("Correct!");
        }
        else {
            alert("Wrong!");
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="crypto-two">
            <h3>Level Two</h3>
            <p>Decode Caesar cipher into plaintext - "FxJxExzhboJxkExEx"</p>

            <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="two-answer" name="two-answer" />
            <button onClick={verifyAnswer}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const CryptoThree = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    function verifyAnswer() {
        let input = inputRef.current.value;
        let answer =  "SHA256".toLowerCase();
        
        if (input === answer) {
            alert("Correct!, completed the exercise");   
        }
        else {
            alert("Wrong!");
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="crypto-three">
            <h3>Level Three</h3>
            <p>Identify the type of the hash (Type only the hash type, with no spaces) - "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"</p>

            <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="three-answer" name="three-answer" />
            <button onClick={verifyAnswer}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const Cryptography = () => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState("crypto-one");

    return (
        <div className="cryptography">
            <h1>Cryptography</h1>
            <DisplayTimer />
            <div className="crypto-container">
                <CryptoOne />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export { Cryptography };
```

Here, i have this cryptography function that will display a question and if it is correct, that question will be replaced with another.
I have 3 seperate functions CryptoOne, CryptoTwo and CryptoThree which will be displayed in function Cryptography. So that means if the answer for the question for CryptoOne is correct, then it will be replaced with CryptoTwo and so on. So my questions is HOW DO I DO IT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER TO YOUR LAST COMMENT TO HANDLE TIMER**

Instead of using `react-useinterval` you could create a `useTimer()` hook of your own

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const useTimer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
  const minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
  const seconds = time % 60;

  let interval = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    };
  }, [setTime]);

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  };

  return { hours, minutes, seconds, stopTimer };
};

export default useTimer;
```

You can maintain a activeIndex state in Cryptography component. And have a changeSlide method which increments `activeSlideIndex` by 1 everytime the answer is correct. As shown below

**TIMER RELATED COMMENT**
Use that hook in `Cryptography` component. Pass `hours`, `minutes` & `seconds` as props in `DisplayTimer` component. And pass `stopTimer` function to `CryptoThree` component & use it when final answer is complete

```js
const Cryptography = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("crypto-one");
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(1);
  const { hours, minutes, seconds, stopTimer } = useTimer();

  const incrementIndex = () => {
    setActiveIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="cryptography">
      <h1>Cryptography</h1>
      <DisplayTimer hours={hours} minutes={minutes} seconds={seconds} />
      <div className="crypto-container">
        {activeSlideIndex === 1 && <CryptoOne changeIndex={incrementIndex} />}
        {activeSlideIndex === 2 && <CryptoTwo changeIndex={incrementIndex} />}
        {activeSlideIndex === 3 && <CryptoThree stopTimer={stopTimer} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const DisplayTimer = ({ hours, minutes, seconds }) => {
  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <h3>Timer</h3>
      <p>
        {hours.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:
        {minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:
        {seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0")}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can pass this `changeSlide()` method as a prop in every component.
And call it whenever the answer is correct

```js
const CryptoOne = ({ changeIndex }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  function verifyAnswer() {
    if (inputRef.current.value === "c6e24b99a8054ab24dd0323530b80819") {
      alert("Correct!");
      changeIndex();
    } else {
      alert("Wrong!");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="crypto-one">
      <h3>Level One</h3>
      <p>
        Convert this plaintext into an MD5 hash - "RollingStonesGatherNoMoss"
      </p>

      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="one-answer" name="one-answer" />
      <button onClick={verifyAnswer}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const CryptoTwo = ({ changeIndex }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  function verifyAnswer() {
    if (inputRef.current.value === "IaMaHackerManHaHa") {
      alert("Correct!");
      changeIndex();
    } else {
      alert("Wrong!");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="crypto-two">
      <h3>Level Two</h3>
      <p>Decode Caesar cipher into plaintext - "FxJxExzhboJxkExEx"</p>

      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="two-answer" name="two-answer" />
      <button onClick={verifyAnswer}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const CryptoThree = ({stopTimer) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  function verifyAnswer() {
    let input = inputRef.current.value;
    let answer = "SHA256".toLowerCase();

    if (input === answer) {
      alert("Correct!, completed the exercise");
      stopTimer(); // Use stopTimer here when exercise is complete
    } else {
      alert("Wrong!");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="crypto-three">
      <h3>Level Three</h3>
      <p>
        Identify the type of the hash (Type only the hash type, with no spaces)
        - "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
      </p>

      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="three-answer" name="three-answer" />
      <button onClick={verifyAnswer}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: My friend @Pratik Wadekar Thank you so much man, was struggling with this for a very long time.

Comment: Yes and then i have that timer on top, so i want to stop it when CryptoThree is also correct. Any suggestions for that. Thanks again.

Comment: Well you are using `react-useinterval` which provides useInterval hook but that does not return anything. So it is hard to clear an existing ongoing interval.